# Does node.js code run to completion even if interrupted by a signal handler?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have the following code in node.js:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
    process.exit(0);
});

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   console.error(i);
}
```

Will the code always print all the numbers up to 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy enough to test:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  console.log('*** GOT SIGTERM ***');
  process.exit(0);
});

process.kill(process.pid);

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
 console.error(i);
}
```

The results show that, indeed, the `for` loop does run to completion, but **this is misleading**. The `for` loop blocks I/O. Because Node is single-threaded, `process.exit(0)` doesn’t get called until the `for` loop is done.

A more illustrative example:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  console.log('*** GOT SIGTERM ***');
  process.exit(0);
});

process.kill(process.pid);

setTimeout(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   console.error(i);
  }
}, 1000);
```

Here we use `setTimeout` to wait 1 second before doing the `for` loop. Node’s event loop will continue to run during that time, so the `process.on('SIGTERM')` will be called before the `for` loop begins. And the results are different: **the for loop does not run at all**.

Once `process.exit(0)` is called, the app ends and nothing else is executed. The difference between the two examples is *when* `process.exit(0)` is called.